# Crossbrowser platform independent http image upload library ( mac / linux / windows / ipad )

Tags: javascript, http, file-upload, cross-browser

In the era of gazilion different browsers, it is harder and harder to make usable photo uploads on a webpage available for all users.

I search for a library that provides http file uploads (multiple is a nice to have but not a must), with a progress bar, that works on:

Linux (Chrome, Firefox, Konqueror)
Windows (Chrome, Firefox, IE 7+)
Mac (Chrome, Firefox, Safari)
iPad (Mobile Safari)

Does such a library exists ?

Comment: Basically, any Flash based one.

Comment: yeah, especially for iPad... it is too complicated for the normal user to get flash on the iPad device, so this is not a option

Comment: Yes, you are right. Just curious, what other options are there for Macs if it does not support Flash?

Comment: I don't know, this is why I posted this question

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) widget ([demo here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)). It supports multi file/image upload (simultaneous), progress bar, thumbnail preview, cancel and delete images.

It works on all popular browsers. Make sure to try the demo on iPad.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody stumbling on this, check out Dropzone.js: http://www.dropzonejs.com